# (Beginner) Questions about the Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have some questions related to the Big O notation:

---

```
n^3 =  Big Omega(n^2)
```

This is true because:

```
n^3 >= c * n^2 for all n >= n0

-> Lim(n-> infinity) = n^3/n^2 >= c
```

Then I used L'Hospital and got `6n/2 >= c` which is true if I for example choose `c` as `1` and `n0` as `1`

---

Are my thoughts right on this one ?

Now  I got two pairs:

`log n` and `n/log n`, do they lie in `Theta, O` or somewhere else ? Just tell me where they lie, then I can do the proof by myself.

`n^(log n)` and `2^n` follows vice versa

---

And at last:

```
f(n) = O(n) -> f(n)^2 = O(n^2)

f(n)g(n) = O(f(n)g(n))
```

The question is: **Are these statements correct** ?

I would say yes to the first one, I don't really know why and it seems like there is a hidden trick to this, but I don't really know, could someone help me out here ?

The second one should be true if `g(n)` lies in `O(n)` ,but I don't really know here either.

Comment: Using L'Hospital  to calculate Lim(n-> infinity) n^3/n^2 , is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're right here.

---

As for `log(n)` and `n/log(n)` you can check it by finding the `lim log(n)/(n/log(n))` and vice versa.
Using the fact that `a^b = e^(b*ln(a))`:
`n^log(n) = e^(log(n) * log(n)) < e^(n^2) = e^e^(2*log(n)) < (e^e)^(2*n) = O(C^n)`, and `2^n` is also `Big O(C^n)`.

---

Let's use the definition and some properties of the Big O(f):

- `O(f) = f * O(1)`
- `O(1) * O(1) = O(1)`

Now we have:
`f(n)^2 = f(n) * f(n) = O(n) * O(n) = n * O(1) * n * O(1) = n^2 * O(1) = O(n^2)`.
`f(n)g(n) = f(n)g(n) * O(1) = O(f(n)g(n))`.
So, yes, it is correct.

Comment: Big omega is different from big O. In fact it is sort of the opposite. The OP is not wrong.